# Singleton as a app resource- 2 instances created?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I've got a Windows 8.1 Store application.
Have a singleton class in which I keep some data. I've defined a static property of the singleton as an app resource-

```
 Application.Current.Resources.Add("CSettings", CSettings.Instance.Data);
```

and I'm binding various xaml properties to appropriate properties in it

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="m_cConnectionModeToggle" OnContent="Enabled" OffContent="Disabled"  
IsOn="{Binding IsTCPConnection, Source={StaticResource CSettings}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I thought that I'd be able to access my singleton through the usual ...Instance getter- but when I go to CSettings.Instance.Data I'm getting a different instance from the one that's been bound (and changed).

Are there 2 singleton instances of the same class being created here?

One at CSettings with the .Instance getter and another on this.Resources["CSettings"] ?

Did I fail in implementation somewhere? I mean is this a plausible approach to having a changeable, application- wide resource, that I'd be able to both bind and use programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me that when you add a value to the Resources dictionary it doesn't store it as a reference but it creates a new value.

My suggestion would be to use an IoC container like the ones used by MVVM frameworks. For example SimpleIoc from MVVM light. You don't have to implement MVVM in your application, just use the container.

The way this would work would be to create a class and register it as a resource in App.xaml. In that class register your container like that

App.xaml

```
<MyC:MyClass x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:MyC="clr-namespace:MyProject.MyClassFolder" />
```

MyClass.cs

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);


SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyData>();

public MyData { get {return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyData>();}}
```

Note: You will need Microsoft.Services.ServiceLocation and Galasoft.Mvvmlight.Ioc.SimpleIoc you can get both from Nuget.

Then in xaml you can access the MyData.IsTCPConnection field like that

```
IsOn="{Binding MyData.IsTCPConnection, Source={StaticResource Locator}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and in code

```
 MyData myData = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyData>();
 myData.IsTCPConnection = ...;
```